# Video Full Screen not Working in ios Swift AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

This is my code:

```
self.playerView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2));
self.playerView?.setVideoGravity(AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill)
self.playerView?.setMovieToPlayer(mp)
```

First line to transform from portrait to landscape...
mp is AVPlayer..

Storyboard pic and black color is the `playerView` inside `ViewController MainView`

[image]

and the constraints are

```
trailing = Player View.trailing
Player View.bottom = Bottom Layout Guide.top
Player View.top = top
Player View.leading = leading
```

The output is: View is not Occupying the full screen but leaving some space at left and right

[image]

Somebody help please?
Atleast Provide some tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` that you specify when initialize your `playerView`. According to [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Video_Gravity):

> AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
>
> Specifies that the player should preserve the video’s aspect ratio and fill the layer’s bounds.

Comment: Not working ... Please provide me any tutorial with AVPlayer, FullScreen ,Swift , AutoLayout

Comment: @Jack can you get more details? What you want and what you get.

Comment: Yeah, I need a UIView in landscape mode and It should occupy full Screen and I should display AvPlayer Video in that view as fullscreen...

Comment: @Jack, to achieve your goal I follow [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html) tutorial. But it's on Obj-C. If you will  need help with transporting this code to Swift - let me know. I've got ported code for my project.

Comment: Hi did you port the code to Swift? Having trouble with this question, though it may be different as all we want to do is capture and render at the same size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704032/swift-video-records-at-one-size-but-renders-at-wrong-size